# How to make a dropdown value automatically selected if that value is passed in params in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-routing, angular5

When I route to my angular 5 application ,I need to check if in the params whether account is present or not.If account is present I need to set that value in some this.appState and when I move to my home page I have a dropdown for account type which should have this value automatically selected using the this.appState.get .how can we do this can someone help.below is my code

```
 localhost:3000/#/login?customerid=admin&account=saving
```

login.component.js

```
private accounttype : string;
    if(params['account']){
     this.appState.set('accounttype',params['account'] );
 }
```

home.html

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select (change) = "onAccountTypeSelection()" required="required" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="accountType">
      <option value="" selected>Select Account Type</option>
      <option *ngFor="let account of accountTypes" [value]="account.id">{{account.name}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

home.component.js

```
 if(this.appState.get('accounttype')){

//code to make dropdown value automatically selected
}
public ngOnInit() {
this.accountTypes = Array<KeyValuePair>();
this.accountTypes.push(new KeyValuePair('Saving', 'Saving'));
this.accountTypes.push(new KeyValuePair('Checking', 'Checking'));
this.accountType = '';
}
```

Thanks